# How do i write a function that iterates through a list of sets of elements of varied amounts extracting sequential arrays of 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby

i have a long list of  sets of elements of varied amounts . For each line, I want to extract only those sets which have 4 elements or more  and push them into a separate array  . If the set has more than 4 elements , I want to extract each set of 4 elements within them. for instance

```
a,b,c 
a,b,c,d 
d,b,c,a
a,b,d,c,a,d
a,d
```

returns

```
result = [ [a,b,c,d], [d,b,c,a] , [a,b,d,c], [b,d,c,a], [d,c,a,d] ]
```

notice that the second to the last set of elements produces 3 arrays at the end  of the result array.

How would i write a JS or Ruby function/method to return this kind of result ??

Comment: What is this _"list of sets of elements"_? An array of arrays, a huge string, something else?

Comment: @NickPerez: Define what you mean by _set_. It can't be the Ruby data type `Set`, because what you show as desired result is not a *Set* in the Ruby-sense, nor in the mathematical sense. AFIK, JavaScript doesn't have something called **set** either.

Comment: @NickPerez : Also please discuss either javascript or Ruby in a single question. The languages are different enough, that I don't see how such a solution can be reasonably discussed for both in an uniform way.

Comment: each "set" is as shown - a line with string elements. what you see above is a snippet of a TXT file that i have to iterate through . i Just need A solution .whether one choses ruby or js  its up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Ruby solution: first select the arrays which are big enough, then put all consecutive series of 4 elements in the result.

```
input = [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','c','d'], ['d','b','c','a'], ['a','b','d','c','a','d'], ['a','d']]

p input.select{|ar| ar.size >= 4}.flat_map{|ar| ar.each_cons(4).to_a }

# =>[["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["d", "b", "c", "a"], ["a", "b", "d", "c"], ["b", "d", "c", "a"], ["d", "c", "a", "d"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I looked at the array if it is length of 4 I just pushed it into the result if it is more then 4 then I iterated over it to push every one instance of 4, I hope this is what you wanted.

```js
const input = [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','c','d'], ['d','b','c','a'], ['a','b','d','c','a','d'], ['a','d']]
const result = []

input.forEach(arr => {
  if (arr.length === 4) {
    result.push(arr)
  } else if (arr.length > 4) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 3; i++) {
      result.push(arr.slice(0 + i, 4 + i))
    }
  }
})

console.log('result = ', result)

//result = [ [a,b,c,d], [d,b,c,a] , [a,b,d,c], [b,d,c,a], [d,c,a,d] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Ruby solution.

```
input = [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','c','d'], ['d','b','c','a'],
         ['a','b','d','c','a','d'], ['a','d']]
```

```
input.each_with_object([]) do |a,arr|
  a.each_cons(4) { |a4| arr << a4 } if a.size > 3
end
  #=> [["a", "b", "c", "d"], ["d", "b", "c", "a"], ["a", "b", "d", "c"],
  #    ["b", "d", "c", "a"], ["d", "c", "a", "d"]]
```

See [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).